# WCF Restful Service: The body encoding changes automagically?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I have a WCF Service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public class SomeService
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/test", Method = "POST")]
    public string Test()
    {
        using (var reader = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents())
        {
            var content = reader.ReadOuterXml().Replace("<Binary>", "").Replace("</Binary>", "");
            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

And has a config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Project.SomeService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Project.SomeService"
                  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_SomeService" behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior_SomeService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding_SomeService">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="endpointBehavior_SomeService">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

But when I call it using fiddler with this url with `POST` method:

```
http://localhost:1111/SomeService.svc/Test
```

with the body:

```
asdasd
```

it returns `YXNkYXNk` instead, why was it like this?

My Code is in C#, framework 4, build in VS2010Pro.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Something* is base64-encoding either the result or the request. The ASCII bytes for `asdasd` come out as `YXNkYXNk` when base64-encoded.

It's not clear how you're providing the body, but I suggest you look at the exact request/response using [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) or [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com) to work out where the base64-encoding is happening, then work out why, then fix it.

EDIT: Now I've had a closer look at your code, it seems reasonably clear.

Your request is meant to include *binary* data, presumably - which is why you've got a `Binary` tag within the XML. You're deciding to ignore that, and just treat the XML representation of the binary data as text - but you shouldn't. Binary data is represented in XML via base64. So, you should:

- Parse the XML *as XML* rather than getting the outer XML as a string and then performing string operations
- Fetch the contents of the `Binary` tag as a string
- Use `Convert.FromBase64String` to get the original binary data
- *If you believe* that binary data was originally text, use `Encoding.GetString` to convert it back

Comment: What is not clear on _providing the body_? I use Fiddler and put `asdasd` in the _body_ field, or is it the server side _on how it retrieve the body_? Please help.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona: Not having Fiddler right in front of me, I don't know from memory what options there are. But please see my edit - basically Fiddler and the server are both treating this as *binary* data, but you're not decoding from the base64 representation of that.